# STM32H7 MPU shareable memory attribute and strongly ordered memory type

Tags: caching, stm32, cortex-m, arm-mpu

I am confused by some of the attributes of the STM32H7 MPU.

I've read several documents: STM32H7 reference and programming manual, STMicro application note on MPM, etc...

I've understood that shareable is exactly equivalent to non-cacheable (at least on a single core STM32H7). Is it correct ?

I need to define a MPU region for a QSPI Flash memory. A document from MicroChip (reference TB3179) indicates that the QSPI memory should be configured as Strongly Ordered. I don't really understand why ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: I've understood that shareable is exactly equivalent to non-cacheable (at least on a single core STM32H7). Is it correct?

Here's an ST guide to MPU configuration:

https://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/support/learning/stm32-education/stm32-moocs/STM32_MPU_tips.html

> If some area is **Cacheable and Shareable**, **only instruction cache is used** in STM32F7/H7

> As STM32 [F7 and H7] microcontrollers don't contain any hardware
> feature for keeping data coherent, setting a region as **Shareable**
> means that **data cache is not used** in the region.  If the region is not
> shareable, data cache can be used, but data coherency between bus
> masters need to be ensured by software.

**Shareable on STM32H7 seems to be implicitly synonymous with non-cached access when INSTRUCTION_ACCESS_DISABLED** (Execute Never, code execution disabled).

Furthermore,

https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/f/cortex-a-forum/5468/shareability-memory-attribute

> The **sharability** attribute tells the processor it must do whatever
> is necessary to allow that data to be shared.  **What that really
> means depends on the features of a particular processor.**
>
> On a processor with multi-CPU hardware cache coherency; the
> shareability attribute is a signal to engage the cache coherency logic.
> For example A57 can maintain cache-coherency of shareable data within
> the cluster and between clusters if connected via a coherent
> interconnect.
>
> **On a processor without hardware cache coherency**, such as Cortex-A8, the only way to share the data is to push it out of the
> cache as you guessed.  On A8 **shareable, cacheable memory ends up
> being treated as un-cached.**

Someone, please correct me if I'm wrong - it's so hard to come by definitive and concise statements on the topic.

---

> Question: I need to define an MPU region for a QSPI Flash memory.
> QSPI memory should be configured as Strongly Ordered. I don't really understand why?

The MPU guide above claims at least two points: **prevent speculative access and prevent writes from being fragmented** (e.g. interrupted by reading operations).

> Speculative memory read may cause high latency or even system error
> when performed on external memories like SDRAM, or Quad-SPI.
>
> External memories even don't need to be connected to the microcontroller,
> but its memory range is accessible by speculative read because by
> default, its memory region is set as Normal.
>
> **Speculative access is never made to Strongly Ordered and Device memory
> areas.**

> Strongly Ordered memory type is used in memories which need to have each write be a **single transaction**

> For Strongly Ordered memory region **CPU waits for the end of memory access** instruction.

Finally, I suspect that alignment can be a requirement from the memory side which is adequately represented by a memory type that enforces aligned read/write access.

https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0489/d/memory-system/axim-interface/memory-system-implications-for-axi-accesses

> However, Device and Strongly-ordered memory are always Non-cacheable.
> Also, **any unaligned access to Device or Strongly-ordered memory
> generates alignment UsageFault** and therefore does not cause any AXI
> transfer. This means that the access examples are given in this chapter
> never show unaligned accesses to Device or Strongly-ordered memory.

---

UsageFault : Without explicit configuration, UsageFault defaults to calling the HardFault handler. Differentiated error handling needs to be enabled in *SCB System Handler Control and State Register* first:

```
SCB->SHCSR |= SCB_SHCSR_MEMFAULTENA_Msk // will also be set by HAL_MPU_Enable()
    | SCB_SHCSR_BUSFAULTENA_Msk
    | SCB_SHCSR_USGFAULTENA_Msk;
```

UsageFault handlers can evaluate UsageFault status register (UFSR) described in https://www.keil.com/appnotes/files/apnt209.pdf.

```
printf("UFSR : 0x%4x\n", (SCB->CFSR >> 16) & 0xFFFF);
```

Comment: As it applies to cortex-m4 most of the attributes are ignored.  They are inherited from the Cortex-A series where they have more meaning.  It seems the cortex-m7 is using some more sophisticated features found in the cortex-a series to increase performance.  I think it maybe helpful to look at Cortex-A caching/buffering information for those programming on the Cortex-m7.